# Getting 404 on Nginx on EC2 and meteor

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor, socket.io, meteorite

I am having a weird issue with nginx throwing a 404 error on javascript files.

See it here:

http://ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Because the meteor application throws a 404, press escape and view the source of the page because meteor has javascript that redirects the entire page if javascript fails to load (A complete fail by meteor IMHO)

You will find that I am properly proxying from port 3000 running node to port 80 through the rendering of the main page.

If you go to http://ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/, you will see the hello world render just fine.

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is the default conf file.

Here is the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
  root /home/meteor/can_i_help_you/can_i_help_you;

  access_log "/home/ubuntu/logs/access.log";
  error_log "/home/ubuntu/logs/error.log" error;

  charset utf-8;

  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;

  # would be awesome if your mobile-app can utilize keep-alives!
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  # enable gzip
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;

  # we only gzip these mime-types (since there's no use to gzip jpegs)
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  # tell-client to cache all 'assets'
  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

  # disable logging for some `common` files
  # Disable logging for favicon
  location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
  }

  # Disable logging for robots.txt
  location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
  }

  # Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
  location ~* (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
  }

  # Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
  location ~* (\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$ {
    return 403;
  }

  # reverse-proxy here, if your have multiple machine/cores would be better to use UPSTREAM so nginx can load-balance requests

  #try_files $uri $uri/ @silly;
  location / {

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_pass         http://ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/;
  }

  #location / {
  #  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  #  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  #  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  #
  #  proxy_pass http://ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/;
  #  proxy_redirect off;
  #}


}
```

Comment: It kinda looks like you're redirecting to yourself in the config, with `proxy_pass` set to the current `server_name`.  Take a look at this gist, which is setup to proxy requests to internal servers: https://gist.github.com/dylants/8609050  It's setup for SSL support, but should give you an idea.

Comment: No the issue is not a redirect.  The redirect is the in javascript files throwing 404 errors.   http://ec2-54-85-163-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com/can_i_help_you.js?14ce80c88a4b0cfc9f7e12fa67a247df664f95c7.  The home page does the redirect with a document.location that the poorly written meteor application employs.  I do not like meteor right now because of this block of javascript. `if (typeof Package === 'undefined' ||
    ! Package.webapp ||
    ! Package.webapp.WebApp ||
    ! Package.webapp.WebApp._isCssLoaded())
  document.location.reload(); 
` are you serious!!!